# Maintain Single Source or apk for Nook and Kindle

Tags: android, apk, kindle-fire, nook

I have to maintain my application in Android Play, Kindle and Nook Stores. I am using camera option in my application. As there is no camera for Nook I have to hide camera option each time when I am publishing to market. So that I have to take two different apks (One for Play store, Kindle and another for Nook.). Is there any way to have single apk to be published  in all the three stores. This will save my time a lot.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it by finding the device Manufacturer for Nook using `Build.MANUFACTURER`. The manufacturer for Nook is "Foxconn".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to detect whether the device has a camera now.

You can use [`PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) and pass [`PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA) as the argument.